# "No difference" or "no different"

Tags: grammaticality

> A: What do you want to eat for dinner?
>
> B : No **difference**/No **different**.

Which is correct and why?

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be **no deference**! Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: If someone asked what you want for dinner and you say, "No deference", that would mean that you refuse to give in to someone else's dinner preference. :-)

Comment: @Fumble: You're just not showing the proper difference to the OP. Deferent strokes for deferent folks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*No difference* is a noun phrase, whereas *no different* is an adjective phrase. Compare:

> This candidate's agenda is no different from that one's.
>
> There is no difference between the agenda of the two candidates.

As regards your particular example, I agree with @Will in that "*anything*" would be a better response than *no difference*. *No different* would be completely wrong.

Comment: Or "no preference".

Comment: Or "It makes no difference to me".

Comment: thanks guys... usually i said no difference.. i mean of no difference is that " There is no difference for me to what eating" so i thought i can put it on short form look like "no difference". Anything is better, but from the grammatical point of view there is no grammatical problem in "no difference" am i right?

Answer (score 6):

Neither one is correct. You would say “**It makes no difference (to me)**”.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "**anything**", "**nothing**", rather than "**no difference**". Please see [make no difference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+no+difference)